# Icons are broken after a clean installation of panopoly profile

Tags: distributions

I have made a clean installation of Panopoly.However icons are broken.I attach an image.
Seems images are not on the correct folder.
How can i fix that?
thanks[image]

Comment: inspect the image element and check the path showing for the image, might be creating a virtual host can fix your issue if your drupal is not directly under your web root.File permissions can be another possibility.

Comment: That screenshot is too small to see clearly. Do you have a larger one?

Comment: nope I don't have another one.What is missing is the Home icon of drupal on top left,icon notices e.g.for updates etc

Comment: Also the handlers of all taxonomy terms are not visible